# Is there any way to have re.sub report out on every replacement it makes?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

TL;DR: How to get `re.sub` to print out what substitutions it makes, including when using groups?

Kind of like having a verbose option, is it possible to have `re.sub` print out a message every time it makes a replacement? This would be very helpful for testing how multiple lines of `re.sub` is interacting with large texts.

I've managed to come up with this workaround for simple replacements utilizing the fact that the `repl` argument can be a function:

```
import re

def replacer(text, verbose=False):
    def repl(matchobj, replacement):
        if verbose:
            print(f"Replacing {matchobj.group()} with {replacement}...")
        return replacement
    text = re.sub(r"[A-Z]+", lambda m: repl(m, "CAPS"), text)
    text = re.sub(r"\d+", lambda m: repl(m, "NUMBER"), text)
    return text

replacer("this is a 123 TEST 456", True)

# Log:
#   Replacing TEST with CAPS...
#   Replacing 123 with NUMBER...
#   Replacing 456 with NUMBER...
```

However, this doesn't work for groups--it seems `re.sub` automatically escapes the return value of `repl`:

```
def replacer2(text, verbose=False):
    def repl(matchobj, replacement):
        if verbose:
            print(f"Replacing {matchobj.group()} with {replacement}...")
        return replacement
    text = re.sub(r"([A-Z]+)(\d+)", lambda m: repl(m, r"\2\1"), text)
    return text

replacer2("ABC123", verbose=True) # returns r"\2\1"

# Log:
#   Replacing ABC123 with \2\1...
```

Of course, a more sophisticated `repl` function can be written that actually checks for groups in `replacement`, but at that point that solution seems too complicated for the goal of just getting `re.sub` to report out on substitutions. Another potential solution would be to just use `re.search`, report out on that, then use `re.sub` to make the replacement, potentially using the `Pattern.sub` variant in order to specify `pos` and `endpos` to save the `sub` function from having to search the whole string again. Surely there's a better way than either of these options?

Comment: From the  [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub): "if it is a string, any backslash escapes in it are processed". However when `repl` is a function, there is no backslash escape processing, so `r'\1\2'` is passed exactly as that, i.e. you will have to process groups yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`matchobj.expand(replacement)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.expand) which will process the replacement string and make the substitutions:

```py
import re

def replacer2(text, verbose=False):
    def repl(matchobj, replacement):
        result = matchobj.expand(replacement)
        if verbose:
            print(f"Replacing {matchobj.group()} with {result}...")
        return result
    text = re.sub(r"([A-Z]+)(\d+)", lambda m: repl(m, r"\2\1"), text)
    return text

print(replacer2("ABC123", verbose=True)
```

Output:

```
Replacing ABC123 with 123ABC...
123ABC
```

A generic example that extends `re.sub` with a verbose option and allows group patterns to be used by replacement functions:

```py
import re

def sub2(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0, verbose=False):
    def helper(match, repl):
        result = match.expand(repl(match) if callable(repl) else repl)
        if verbose:
            print(f'offset {match.start()}: {match.group()!r} -> {result!r}')
        return result
    return re.sub(pattern, lambda m: helper(m, repl), string, count, flags)

# replace three digits with their reverse
print(sub2(r'(\d)(\d)(\d)', r'\3\2\1', 'abc123def45ghi789', verbose=True))
# replace three digits with their reverse, and two digits wrap with parentheses
print(sub2(r'(\d)(\d)(\d)?',
           lambda m: r'(\1\2)' if m.group(3) is None else r'\3\2\1', 
           'abc123def45ghi789', verbose=True))
```

Output:

```
offset 3: '123' -> '321'
offset 14: '789' -> '987'
abc321def45ghi987
offset 3: '123' -> '321'
offset 9: '45' -> '(45)'
offset 14: '789' -> '987'
abc321def(45)ghi987
```

Comment: This makes sense--according to the docs it seems like `Match.expand` itself uses `Pattern.sub`, but at least that doesn't have to be done with too much effort! Also, a minor edit: I think you want to also add `Match.expand` to the return value of the function.

Comment: @Zachary Thanks, missed that since the OP's code didn't print the return value.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a single regex match on the alternation `[A-Z]+|\d+`.  Then, in the callback function, do a switch based on the actual match found and log appropriately.

import re

```
def repl(m):
    if re.search(r'^[A-Z]+$', m.group()):
        print("Replacing " + m.group() + " with CAPS")
        return "CAPS"
    else:
        print("Replacing " + m.group() + " with NUMBER")
        return "NUMBER"

text = "this is a 123 TEST 456"
text = re.sub(r'[A-Z]+|\d+', lambda m: repl(m), text)
print(text)
```

This prints:

```
Replacing 123 with NUMBER
Replacing TEST with CAPS
Replacing 456 with NUMBER
this is a NUMBER CAPS NUMBER
```